# Force MS SQL Service Account to re-authenticate

Tags: sql-server

So here's the deal:
- SQLserver.exe running as domain\myserviceaccount

The (network) backups are running based on the SQLserver.exe service, so the network share is accessed as domain\myserviceaccount.

Now, I made some changes to the share (secured with an AD Security Group and domain\myserviceaccount is a member of it). When I run as or map the drive with domain\myserviceaccount everything works fine. However, the backups are failing. The only way to have this to work so far, is to restart the sqlserver.exe service.

Am I missing something here? I tried rebooting the file share server to make sure all sessions were cleared and also tried logging on as myserviceaccount on that server, nothing. Tried a klist purge, 0.

Any idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a Windows account logs on to the domain the session receives a ticket that includes all of the group memberships.  Accordingly, if you add the account to a new group, it will not be in effect for sessions that are already logged in.  So you'll need to either:

- Restart the SQL Server service
- Add the user account specifically to the share permissions as a temporary solution until the next time the SQL Server service is restarted
- Change the path of the backup config to use an IP address instead of a servername--again, temporarily.  This will cause the connection to bypass Kerberos and use NTLM authentication, which will pick up the group membership (not 100% sure this will work for you, but it's totally a thing).

Comment: Thanks Tony. Yeah this is what I expected. The SQL backup was targeting a share behind DFS, tried targeting the share directly and didn't work. Didn't try by IP though. For the time being I've used option 2 and set a reminder to  go and clean that up, perhaps after these SQL servers have gone through the patching cycle.